# Creating a standard Android preferences dialog

Tags: android, user-interface

New Android developer here - I'm hoping this is simple.
I want to create a "row-based" prefs dialog, like you see in most standard apps.  You know, black background, fading-line separators, bigger/bold label text for each entry, smaller description text, perhaps a checkbox/down arrow.

Is there a standard object in the Android API for this?  If not, how do people usually create these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a special `Activity` for that kind of view called `PreferenceActivity`.

You can find a full example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/PreferencesFromCode.html).

HTH

Thomas

EDIT: this example is a code based preference dialog, but there is another way to do with the xml layout file.

Comment: That code example is now a 404, and I can't seem to find the example anywhere else now.  Any newer source?

Comment: Have a look at the `PreferenceActivity` javadoc, there is an example also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html